# Unrolling of 'm' dependent loops

Tags: loops, time-complexity

Consider I have the following nested `for-loops`:

```
for(i1=1 to n)
   for(i2=1 to i1)
       for(i3=1 to i2)
           for(i4=1 to i3)
               for(i5=1 to i4)
                   count++;
```

How many times will `count` be incremented?

If there are 'm' such dependent loops, how can we compute the value of count variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try some number and get to the answer. (in your example take `m = 5` you will get `1,6,21,56,126` for `n` equal `1,2,3,4,5`)

**Hint** - it will be `Binomial coefficients C(n,5)` (you can use [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C6%2C21%2C56%2C126&language=english&go=Search) to find this)

So for `m` nested loop you will get `count` equal to `C(n+m-1,m)` -> because minimum is picking `m` element so the first `m` element in the Binomial coefficients of m is 0 - you can learn more in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Why this is the answer? it actually math question- but simple explanation: check `Pascal's triangle` - it is sum of differences between number - your case, each loop take the sum of both upper ones - in your loop, each one does till the upper index - same methodology